# Volley: get data from server with id then display it in recycler view

Tags: android, server, android-volley

I want to get data from server with id volley library then display the result in recycler view using.

I can send id to server but I can't display data with id in my app
this is my code:

```
private void getData()
    {
        String url ="MY URL";
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CompanyListActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("send data");
        progressDialog.show();

        Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {

                Toast.makeText(CompanyListActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(CompanyListActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,listener,errorListener)
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                HashMap<String ,String> map =new HashMap<>();
                map.put("id","7");
                return map;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - so you want to get the response from server and display some data on the screen? Are you seeing the Toast message that says "OK" after the service call finishes?

Comment: Add your JSON data